# python how to test field contents with regex if

Tags: python, regex

I want to test the contents of a field in a line to see if that field contains \n. I have a field that has multiple occurrences of \n and I'm trying to find and replace all of them with '' or an empty in place of the \n but leave the rest of the contents of the field. There are other characters in the field as well but I'm specifically looking to get rid of these \n characters.

Here's how I've coded it but I'm wondering if I'm using the best Python method and exactly how to test for the string value I'm searching for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

inFile = open('/baddatafile.txt','r')

for line in inFile:
   data = line.strip().split('\t')

   print 'before: %s' % (data[2])
   data[2] = re.sub(r'\n', '', data[2])
   print 'after: %s' % (data[2])
```

This removes one of the occurrences but only the middle one and there are three occurrences in the record I'm using as a test record.

Here's a sample input record:

```
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This \\n is my first \\nstatement one.\\n<div>
```

And sample output that I'd like: either:

```
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my first statement one.<div>
```

or: an empty field

Comment: can you show us input data and expected output??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you can't just use str.replace?

Comment: A line is by definition something between two newlines, including the following newline. `strip` should take care of the newline, so you should not have any newlines in `data`.... EDIT: your posted data contains no tabs, so it's not the real data. Please post real data. Also, is that backslash-then-n, or is it a newline character? When you just say `\n` people will assume the latter.

Comment: Thanks senshin - I probably should have put the sample record data in as code. Is that the change you made to make it appear as intended - in any event, thanks.

Comment: Amadan, the reason why str.replace wouldn't be suitable in this case is because the text interspersed is variable and the number of newline characters in the string varies as well. It seems that re.sub is intended for the case I'm trying to solve but I've not used these functions before. Also, strip didn't remove the newline characters as I can still see them in the field data[2] after the strip.

Comment: Clarify please: are those `\\n` or `\n` in your file? Also use `@` before a username to notify that user that you are replying to them. No notifications get sent otherwise.

Comment: Checking to see if anyone has suggestions on Python method usage for this problem. Thanks

Comment: @Jerry - thanks for the tip regarding using an at sign. It is two backslashes followed by a small n. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jazzmine Ok thank you. If what you used worked, you wouldn't get the output that you have in your question because of some lingering spaces. The advantage of using re is that you can replace optional spaces, for instance like in this [demo](http://ideone.com/XE1Fr6).